# Running the script does not provide any result

Tags: linux, bash, script

> Hello! I am a beginner who is trying to learn bash scripting. I would like to read the user input (hash) using my script. However, when I run the script it just hangs without returning any result. This is how I run my script ./md5.sh ab68ae97c98a18bda63312d263d6061c. Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash
read hashinput
Getpath="$( find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + | grep "($hashinput)" )"
echo $Getpath
exit
```

Comment: "This is how I run my script `./md5.sh ab68ae97c98a18bda63312d263d6061c`" – Command line arguments are not standard input. Your script executes `read` and waits for you to type something. This is not an answer because there is no question in your "question".

Comment: Oh I see thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears your script is expecting input differently.   As per @KamilMaciorowski comment the way your script is currently run you would need to get the input from STDIN to work - so you could run your script as follows:

```
 echo ab68ae97c98a18bda63312d263d6061c | ./md5.sh
```

Which will provide the hash a...c into stdout for the script to parse.

If you want to take the hash as a command line argument as per your example usage, maybe try the following script instead:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 if [ -z "$1" ]
 then
      echo "Usage $0 hash"
      exit 
 fi

 Getpath=$( find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + | grep "$1" ) 
 echo "$Getpath"
 exit
```

$1 above is the first argument given to the script.  I'm not sure why you enquoted the rightside of Getpath in double quotes.

Comment: Also, the above script is quite inefficient, doing a full md5sum check on all files in the current directory and its sub-directories every time its run.  Depending on your goal, you might want to change the way you do this - for example a script which creates an md5sum of all files and stores them in a known file (which you would run periodically - and possibly incrementally - or when the directory list has changed), and a separate trivial script to just grep that list for each hash.

Answer (score 0):

With this script, it is expecting an answer after you execute ./md5.sh.

For example, your code is meaning that you do:

```
./md5.sh
(md5_hash)
```

for input.

But because you are doing `./md5.sh (md5_hash)`, it does nothing with your input (because it is not the correct input, it is a script argument).

You could do add what @davidgo is recommending, but you could also do:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "MD5 Sum/Hash:" 
read hashinput
Getpath="$( find . -type f -exec md5sum {} + | grep "($hashinput)" )"
echo $Getpath
exit
```

to create like a prompt.

like:

```
$ ./md5.sh
MD5 Sum/Hash: (md5_hash)
```

That's how I made prompts with shell scripting.

So there are essentially two ways this could go:

1. You create a text prompt with `echo` before you `read` the input
2. You could follow @davidgo and add the code to do arguments.